# Required variable that relies on union type params throws not assignable in typescript

Tags: typescript

My class constructor prop uses `type union` to require either `a` or `b` as a property. In the constructor, a `value` variable is created based on either `a` or `b` is defined. This `value` is then used in another class constructor that requires `value` as a string. The `value` type is `string | undefined`, therefor, it throws an error:

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

How can this be solved? In practice, `value` is of a more complicated type than a string. So I can't create a default value for it with `let value = '';`. Also using `if (value)` is unnecessary because a or b would always be defined.

Example code:

```
interface aWithoutB {
    a: string,
    b?: never,
}

interface bWithoutA {
    a?: never,
    b: string,
}

type aOrB = aWithoutB | bWithoutA;

type stringValue = {
    value: string;
}

class Value {
    constructor(value:stringValue) {
        return {
            value
        }
    }
}

class AOrB {
    constructor({a,b}: aOrB) {
        let value; // In practice, value is of a more complicated type than a string. So I can't create a default value for it e.g. `let value = '';`
        if (a) {
            value = a
        } else if (b) {
            value = b
        }
        // Also using if (value) is unnecessary here because a OR b would always be defined.
        const valueObject = new Value({value}); // Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'
    }
}
```

Link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAjgdWGAFgewK5gBCyA3gFDKWoBcyAzmFKAOYA0FVARgPy0gQA3aOwC+ZMqEixEKThmz4wAQVIdKcXsn5Co7Ksk60GTEGzJiyYAJ4AHFHADyUYgF5U83AWIAfAx8VKANzi1nb0jCwAanAANngobuT6ArHxRhGmwRYIMXB0dMjRcShJVAg4IMZ4CGA4UAAUKcXUxlGpEACUqvr6UBBgeFAg3T2jTfFqPWL6Ytm5+chKTsSllOWVjNW1DSRwrJwitI7OXas9Mf3I4xCByAD0d8gAksM2UIhgwEisV+3IwAUcDBUMgALZ1FDlUE2GJfOCQAAmyFCKGwcGGcHCJmYADpkABlHDPZAIdEAcjAJL68PsyAREHgeBilOuyBgdX+lIgONxyAABhcWX83GSyYE+ZN9MBgfU4KdJaNfsVkG44ArKCJkBAYnQUNLkPVOPLFT1WW5OOrkNNFQ9FjqiXg6Cx-jLrl0Acg8CB+Eh8nAoFZkFhoLIIKTHbSHAAlAzIADu+BiSNicbgVgKnBQ9JgoAgCJxlvWDCV8QcnAAVmHKW5+HHCu16iRriIOrdbQAVWwoMmtUzIXxe7O5hFk-4FEA4Sl5J3MEBwTgXZFElHIHsZZhkvGdsJkwcM4ejj0Tqf5YCz+eL2rIrur3sbyazMhAA)

Answer (score 1):

Why compiler not picking up that one of attribute always there - open question.

We can make it working with additional type predicate:

```
function isA(x: aOrB): x is aWithoutB {
  return (x as aWithoutB).a !== undefined;
}

class AOrB {
    constructor(x: aOrB) {
        let value;
        if (isA(x)) {
            value = x.a;
        } else {
            value = x.b
        } 
        // Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'stringValue'.
        const valueObject = new Value({value});
    }
}
```